# Regular call to stored procedure doesn't return a record

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have created a stored procedure on my schema called "get_cat":

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_cat(
    IN  p_cat_id            int(11),
    IN  p_alumni            varchar(10),
    IN  p_status            varchar(10),
    IN  p_order_by          varchar(100),
    IN  p_limit_start       int(11),
    IN  p_limit_end     int(11)
)
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM Cats
        WHERE cat_id=CASE WHEN p_cat_id=0 THEN cat_id ELSE p_cat_id END
            AND alumni=CASE WHEN p_alumni='' THEN alumni ELSE p_alumni END
            AND status=CASE WHEN p_status='' THEN status ELSE p_status END
        ORDER BY p_order_by
        LIMIT p_limit_start, p_limit_end;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The collation of the relevant "Cats" fields are `latin1_swedish_ci`.

---

When I call the stored procedure (`CALL get_cat(678, '', '','Name ASC', 0, 500);`) through PHP using a PDO connection, no values are returned, but it doesn't error. So I fire up phpMyAdmin and try the same call (`CALL get_cat(678, '', '','Name ASC', 0, 500);`) and get the same result:

**Call**
[image: Regular syntax call to stored procedure]
**Return**
[image: Result returned from regular syntax call to stored procedure]
This syntax works for me with other hosts.

---

If I use phpMyAdmin to execute the procedure, it generates this syntax, which *does* return the intended record:

```
SET @p0='678'; SET @p1=''; SET @p2=''; SET @p3='Name ASC'; SET @p4='0'; SET @p5='500'; CALL `get_cat`(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5);
```

**Call**
[image: Executing the same stored procedure through phpMyAdmin]
**Return**
[image: Results from executing the same stored procedure through phpMyAdmin]

---

What is going on? Why doesn't a regular call to the SP return a value?

Comment: Please remove screenshots (use plain text instead) and post (relevant) code for `get_cat()`

Comment: @Bohemian: Give me a moment and I'll add the SP create statement. You might notice I have plaintext *and* screenshots, which are used to illustrate what I mean by "When I call...", "...no values are returned", "If I use phpMyAdmin to execute the procedure..." and "...does return the intended record".

Comment: We believe you about it not returning data - just say it, no need to "prove" it

Comment: Frankly, I think it's odd the return doesn't say *anything*, like "no records returned". It might be a clue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the syntax. It turns out the host (in this case, [iPower](http://www.ipower.com/)) does not allow stored procedure calls on a shared database server:

> 07/27/2014 8:07 PM EDT    IPOWER contacted XXXXXX
>
> Comment:
>
> Hello,
>
> Stored procedure is not supported in shared platform.
>
> If you have any further questions, please update this ticket from the
>   Support Console.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Kiran S  Technical Specialist